# Arduino WiFi/ESP8266 WiFi Password Changed

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I am working on a project for a friend who is not very tech savvy involving an ESP8266. It will need to be connected to his WiFi network.

The issue is that he occasionally changed the password to his WiFi network. Since I will not be able to access this device at a moments notice, it needs to be able to adapt to a change in the password. Is this possible with the ESP8266, or should I switch to an Arduino WiFi board, or is something more powerful necessary?

Comment: The most common solution is to have the ESP act like an accesspoint, if it can't connect to the wifi network. It will then host a webpage, where you can set the correct networkname and password.

Comment: The ESPEasy firmware does the trick, but it may not do whatever you preprogranmed it to do

Answer (score 1):

The [WiFiManager](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager) library was written for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible.

Just don't hard-code the password: store it in EEPROM.

A common way of doing it if for the ESP to present a wifi access point which serves a configuration page when it cannot successfully connect to another access point.  Store the SSID and password in EEPROM.

Comment: On my laptop, if the wifi network password changes, I do not need to re-enter the password, it figures it out automatically. Is there a way I can do this on the ESP?

Comment: I think you are mistaken about that.

Comment: Ok, I just realized I can use bluetooth for this project as well. Is there a way I can add a password to bluetooth to restrict access to specific devices?

Comment: That's a new question.

Comment: Bluetooth authentication isn't very strong, you could do an ethernet connection, since these aren't password protected.

Comment: Think about it, you don't want any device to be able to do this.  Imagine you got hacked and someone got your password.  If this was possible, then you wouldn't be able to stop them by changing the password.